# How can I count objects that are in a collection instance using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, collections, instances, select

I have this script which should count all the selected objects in the scene, but it doesn't. It cannot count the 6 monkeys that are part of a collection instance.

Can you help me?

```
import bpy

sel = bpy.context.selected_objects

obj = []
for o in sel:
    obj.append(o)

tot = len(obj)
print("There are %s selected monkeys!" %(tot))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.instance_collection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=instance_collection#bpy.types.Object.instance_collection) to get the reference to the original collection per object and iterate through [`Collection.objects`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html#bpy.types.Collection.objects). Recommend use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out:

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Collection']

>>> C.object.instance_type == 'COLLECTION'
True

>>> len(C.object.instance_collection.objects)
3
```

Basic demo on how to get all objects of a collection instance:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

objs = []
if C.object.instance_type == 'COLLECTION':
    for ob_col in C.object.instance_collection.objects:
        objs.append(ob_col)

print ("{} objects in collection instance".format(len(objs)))
print (objs) # Print object references
```

Basic demo on how to append *all object names in selection* as well as the *object names of the selected collection instances* to one list and and count the items:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

objs = []
for ob in C.selected_objects:    
    if ob.instance_type == 'COLLECTION':
        for ob_col in ob.instance_collection.objects:
            objs.append(ob_col.name)
    else:
        objs.append(ob.name)

print ("{} objects in selection".format(len(objs)))
```